# How to migrate daily data from Oracle table to MySQL table using Shell script?

Tags: mysql, oracle, shell, migration, sqlplus

I needed to insert data to a MySQL table. The data usually comes from the Oracle database by a SQL file  which has some query to get data from Oracle database table.

So i needed to automate this process on a daily basis using Shell script. So it will run the SQL file (Oracle) and get data. The data has to be moved to a specific MySQL table.

So the operation like,

1. Connecting to Oracle server.
2. Executing SQL in that server.
3. Move collected data to the MySQL table.

I want to run that operation as a cron on daily basis.

I am working on LAMPP environment.

Here are my questions,

1. Is there any standard tools available to do that?
2. Can we achieve this using shell script? If so, Please suggest me the steps.
3. Or It would be great if you suggest me your own optimized way.

Thanks,
Raja.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using a cron job,

1. Write a sql file which exports a data from Oracle DB i.e. sql file containing export table command with appropriate where clause
2. Write a sql file which imports data into Mysql DB i.e. similar import file command in Mysql
3. Write a shell file which run both these sql files and verifies the data in Mysql table

Schedule a cron job to run this shell script daily at a specific hr.

Please check import/export file formats on Oracle and Mysql which can be different as one is freeware and other is commercial. If there are differences then you will need some data/file modification otherwise this should be enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So Do we need intermediate files like XML, JSON or CSV? So we can save the fetched data (From Oracle) in that file. Thereafter we can use that to feed into mysql. Am i right?

Comment: Export and Import are utilities present in almost every DB, they allow to store you exported data in either csv or custom seperator format. these files similarly can be imported also with import functionality. you just have find format of file (csv,tab seperated,xml etc) which is supported by oracle and mysql (I think both support csv) and export data in that format and import it.